# How to return a function as subscription from inside of a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, subscribe

I've been returning requests from my functions like this:

```
makeConnection(data: any) {
    console.log('makeConnection');
    return this.api.get(data.url, data.dataToSend);
  }
```

So I can subscribe like this: `makeConnection.subscribe();`

Now I need to check if a variable named `urls` is set before making an API call So I thought of making a promised function like this

```
checkIfUrlsPresent():Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(this.urls) {
        resolve(true);
        return;
      }
      this.api.get('/service', null).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.urls = response.value.urls;
        resolve(true);        
      });
    });
  }
```

And now my service functions look like this:

```
requestService(data) {
 this.checkIfUrlsPresent().then(() => {
      console.log('requestService');
      let dataToSend = this.api.createFormData(data);
      return this.api.post('/service/request/', dataToSend);
    })    
}
```

But now I won't be able to subscribe to my function like `requestService(data).subscribe()`
So my question is how to keep my  present flow working while adding this promise or is there any way to check that my variable is set before making a call while keeping this flow working.

*Note: The problem is that I'm making all my api calls from one files and there are too many functions that calls these APIs so I need this way so that I won't need to make changes in all my pages to check if url is present.*

Comment: `(await requestService()).subsrcibe()` ...

Comment: Why are you returning a promise of an observable? Use one or the other in your service APIs, mixing two different async handling methods is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Subscription is being returned by an inbuilt function which I have no control of and I'm more comfortable with promises. Can you suggest other way that'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. need to return the promise inside the function as well

```
requestService(data) {
    return this.checkIfUrlsPresent().then(() => { // return the promise
      console.log('requestService');
      let dataToSend = this.api.createFormData(data);
      return this.api.post('/service/request/', dataToSend);
    })    
}
```

Comment: Not yet I guess Now I'll need to go to all my API calling functions and make changes like this `requestService.then( service => service.subscribe())` that's what I don't want to do as there are quite a lot of pages and I'll need to make a lot of changes for that.

Comment: I think I'll need to go through all the hardships and implement your code. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have `requestService` return the chained promises, and call `.then` on it:

```
requestService(data) {
  return this.checkIfUrlsPresent().then(() => {
    console.log('requestService');
    let dataToSend = this.api.createFormData(data);
    return this.api.post('/service/request/', dataToSend);
  })
}

// ..

instance.requestService(someData)
  .then(service => service.subscribe())
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice the second part after `//` was quite more then helpful.